# How to do something 60 times in a second with javascript

Tags: javascript, count, division

I believe that it involves setinterval

I've got the second using this

```
var s=today.getSeconds();
```

Then using setinterval

I've got this

```
setInterval(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
```

The question... I don't think I can divide a second by 60 and use that "asynchronously" I think I'm using that word right, a seconds unit divided 60 times, every 1/60th increment something happens

I'm wondering if I should / have to use milliseconds as those units exist, I'd probably just use a ratio or something to make the equivalent of a second / sixty

Comment: setInterval(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 100/6);

Comment: Is there any reason why you need to run something 60 times per second? If this is to render some animation, you should look into `requestAnimationFrame`.

Comment: I'm not sure if I want to use animate, I mean yes I am generating and moving elements at a certain time frame but I will definitely look into this / most likely apply it.

Comment: I"m trying to figure out what repaint is

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As suggested in a comment, since you ask for 60 times per second, it might mean you want to update an animation i.e. change the color, position, shape etc. of some DOM elements on the screen.

For this it's recommended to use 
[`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame) instead of `setInterval`.

So instead of

```
setInterval(function () {
   doSomething();
}, 16)
```

use

```
function myFunction () {
   doSomething();
   requestAnimationFrame(myFunction);
}
requestAnimationFrame(myFunction);
```

This allows browser to perform certain optimizations.

From MDN:

> You should call this method whenever you're ready to update your
>   animation onscreen. This will request that your animation function be
>   called before the browser performs the next repaint. **The number of
>   callbacks is usually 60 times per second, but will generally match the
>   display refresh rate in most web browsers as per W3C recommendation.**
>
> **The callback rate may be reduced to a lower rate when running in
>   background tabs.**

The name `requestAnimationFrame` might be a bit confusing, but you should read it as "please run my `callback` whenever the browser is ready to do a repaint of the screen", i.e. you let the browser decide the exact timing instead of imposing it yourself.

Comment: Thank you I'm going to give this a go, once the project is complete I may mention it here assuming I pull it off, I'm concerned about server usage, it's not so much a computation thing, I mean yes in a way, it's mostly translation.

Comment: Sorry to bring this up, I don't understand what is meant by "update an animation" are animations linear? Eg. they can't follow curvilinear equations? My aim is to define where an element goes using a function, so I'm wondering if this requestanimation thing is still valid / should be what I need to do. I'd love to see a live server consumption output as I run the webpage, I saw this thing Chrome's Dev tools that appear to do exactly just that to show how expensive some frames are to repaint...

Comment: Anything that changes some visual aspect of the webpage (e.g. a position, size, color, borders of a `<div>` etc.) can be considered "an animation", roughly speaking. You would usually want to correlate the animation progress with the time elapsed; for this, you can create a variable that will store the time in milliseconds since the start of the animation, and in the callback function, calculate the difference between the current time and animation start time, and based on that data, adjust what the callback does.

Comment: You could also in theory use `setInterval` of `n` milliseconds and assume that exactly that time passes between two invocations of the callback, but the timeout in `setInterval` is usually the *minimum* time between two invocations; in the long-running webpage those small discrepancies will amount to a significant shift. It's better to always calculate the difference between two timestamps to have best results. OTOH when using `requestAnimationFrame` instead of `setInterval` you don't have the guarantee of the time difference between two invocations, other than *the best the browser can do*.

Comment: I tried both requestAnimationFrame and setInterval, they were both choppy, I don't know if this is a big reason aside from server cost why motion is generally avoided. Or I just didn't do it right. I saw this animation on css tricks about rAF that showed squares filling up a space and it looked smooth although that was a solid color, not a text box with text inside.

Answer (score 2):

```
setInterval(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 1000/60);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var time = 1000/60;  
setInterval(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, time);
```

1000 is milliseconds divided by 60.

But there is a downfall with this approach, if your function doesn't have time to run in that time (a very short timespan) it will not wait until it's finished. So it can have quite disastrous effects on your application.

Then it's probably better to call setTimeout recursively so it will finish executing your function before it's called again.

```
var time = 1000/60;  
(function loop(){
   setTimeout(function(){

      // logic here

      // recurse
      loop();

  }, time);

})();
```

Sure requestAnimationFrame is nice but it's not supported on older browsers. If you want working code in older browsers I would advise using a recursive settTimeout approach. That will work everywhere!

Comment: You mean the next call will be waited until the previous has been executed. Disastrous effects anyway ; ).

Comment: 16 ms is very short, you can have a lot of logic, and various browsers have different speeds of execution.

Answer (score 0):

One sixtieth of a second is approximately 16 milliseconds, so you can do:

```
setInterval(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 16);
```

Comment: @Jonathan - Well you're right, screwed up there! :-)